# How can i reduce the runtime of my code in this question

Tags: python, performance, big-o

Question - Given two strings `needle`and `haystack`, return the index of the first occurrence of `needle` in `haystack`, or `-1` if `needle` is not part of `haystack`. (the question is from [Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-the-index-of-the-first-occurrence-in-a-string/description/))
Samples - Input: `haystack = "sadbutsad", needle = "sad"`
Output: `0`
and
Input: `haystack = "leetcode", needle = "leeto"`
Output: `-1`

My code

```
class Solution:
    def strStr(self, haystack: str, needle: str) -> int:
        if needle not in haystack:
            return -1 
        else:
            for i in range (0, (len(haystack)-len(needle))+1):
                if haystack[i:i+len(needle)] == needle:
                    return i
                    break
```

[image]

Comment: And if the exercise is to do it yourself and not use library calls, the really high performance approaches to substring search involve things like vectorization that you can't do directly in Python but need to call into C or assembly for.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Note that "vectorization" has two meanings. In Python, and especially Numpy related libraries, vectorization means using native function so to speed up computations. In native languages, this means using SIMD instructions (explicitly or not). The former may or may not use SIMD instructions.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski thank you i did not know this, but my goal to solve the question is to understand how it works rather than using an existing function.

Comment: Why would numpy attach a new and different meaning to a perfectly good preexisting term?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i dont have knowledge about vectorization, will definitely read about it.

Comment: @MrTraitor, if your goal is to find out how it works, **read the source code**. That source code is _not_ written in Python.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there is no SIMD on string processes in `numpy`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy more than half of the people who solved the question in python have a better runtime than me, is the only reason im curious on how to reduce runtime

Comment: @roganjosh, there is, in `numpy.char` module

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest shut my mouth, then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Focusing on a pure python solution and not using any built-in functions that do this for you. I can offer some improvements to your code.

You can remember the length of the needle so you don't have to call length as often. Also, you don't need the break after you return. It just returns.

```
class Solution:
    def strStr(self, haystack: str, needle: str) -> int:
        if needle not in haystack:
            return -1 
        else:
            needle_length = len(needle)
            for i in range(len(haystack) - needle_length + 1):
                if haystack[i: i+needle_length] == needle:
                    return i
```

Note: This solution will use slightly more memory because of storing the length as a variable but it will take less time depending on the times it loops

Comment: I did my test with this as well, it's indeed faster than theirs, but only slightly: ~4800 ms.

Comment: @KellyBundy What is slightly faster? Your solution is obviously the optimal solution but using pure python and focusing on improving OP's code was my objective.

Comment: If the goal is to avoid functions like `find()` why are you using the built-in `in`? And do you even need it once you’ve looped through and not found the word?

Comment: Totally makes sense but OP was asking for an improvement to their code

Comment: @Jab yes this did reduce runtime, surprisingly also uses less memory, your edited code runtime = 37ms, memory used = 16mb (on leetcode), while my original code runtime = 40ms, memory used = 16.2mb. Even more surprisingly your edited code uses less memory than @KellyBundy 's code using the existing function ```haystack.find(needle)```

Comment: @Mark hmm you do have a point, i will rewrite my code and do it without using ```in```

Comment: Yours is slightly faster than theirs, 4800 ms versus their 5400 ms.

Comment: @MrTraitor Nah, yours takes about 0.054 ms and theirs about 0.048 ms. Not 40 and 37. Did you see my testing/discussion?

Comment: You could also use `haystack.startswith` instead of slicing. (Partly I'm saying that because your added spaces are a pet peeve I'm sharing with [PEP 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOckQ.png)).

Answer (score 1):

```
class Solution:
    def strStr(self, haystack: str, needle: str) -> int:
        return haystack.find(needle)
```

Proof that it's faster: LeetCode's tests are *tiny*, so I ran the solution 100000 times for each input:

```
class Solution:
    def strStr(self, haystack: str, needle: str) -> int:
        for _ in range(100000):
            result = self.real_strStr(haystack, needle)
        return result
    def real_strStr(self, haystack: str, needle: str) -> int:
        return haystack.find(needle)
```

That gets accepted in about 1300 ms. With yours, it gets accepted in about 5400 ms.

Note that that's about 0.013 ms and 0.054 ms without the repetition. So as often, LeetCode's time of 40 ms that it showed you is almost solely spent by the judge, about 99.9% in this case. Only about 0.1% of the time is from the actual solution code. The time you get is pretty much entirely up to luck, the speed of your solution doesn't matter.

Comment: This answer was already proposed in the comments by @Steven Rumbalski. Subsequent comment suggests that they want to solve the problem without using this built-in function.

Comment: @Bill Doesn't matter. Comments aren't for answering, and comments aren't the question.

Comment: Comments are for clarifying the question. But okay, we'll let the OP decide if your answer is the correct one. That's not for me to say.

Comment: @Bill Comments aren't for clarifying the question, either. Users other than the author can *ask* for clarifications there, but the author is supposed to add information in the question, not in a comment.

Comment: @Bill Anyway, yes, of course this solution is trivial. The value of the answer is mostly in the demonstration/explanation of LeetCode's terrible measuring and the complete meaninglessness of their regular results.

Answer (score -2):

One thing that is a bit inefficient in your code is that you search the whole string first to see if `needle` is in it.  If the Leetcode test data has very few examples where the string is not included then your code will do worse than others.

Is this any faster?

```
class Solution:
    def strStr(self, haystack: str, needle: str) -> int:
        i_start = 0
        n = len(needle)
        while True:
            try:
                i = haystack.index(needle[0], i_start)
            except ValueError:
                return -1
            if haystack[i:i+n] == needle:
                return i
            i_start = i + 1
        return -1
```

Comment: Oh okay.  Do you know why?

Comment: Ah yes good point! I updated the code to deal with that.

Comment: Updated it again.  Any more issues you can see now?

Comment: Now it gets accepted but is about 17 times *slower* than theirs. (I had to reduce my number of repetitions to 10000 and it still took ~9400 ms.)

Comment: Ah okay.  Must be the tests I'm running.  When I tested it it's 35% faster than the OP's code and 25% faster than @Jab's solution and 6.3 times slower than `str.find`.  I'm not on Leetcode so I can't test it there.

Comment: Your latest edit brought it down to ~9.3 times slower than theirs. With `haystack.index(needle[0], i_start)` (and adjusting to that) it would drop to ~6.7 times slower than theirs.

Comment: Yes, very much depends on the tests, of course. With input `'a'*5000 + 'b'*5000, 'b'*5000`, yours is even over 1000 times faster than theirs. Btw I really recommend using `index`'s second parameter. Not only faster but also makes the rest of the code nicer.